# How can I import multiple mysql queries exported as a text with php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to import multiple mysql queries exported as a text by php.
Imported queries looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `custom` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`input_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`custom_section` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`custom_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`custom_price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `custom_section` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`section_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`section_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

.........
```

The list goes on for 20 more queries.

Right now, I am using

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE .....");
```

for each query to do the job. Is there a better way to do this? I feel there must be simpler way to achieve this. I do not wish to import form .sql because .sql files are too vulnerable to download.

Thanks.

Comment: you could use a normal IDE  (as toad or sqlworkbench and exce the code as .SQL file)

Comment: `$mysqli->query(file_get_contents('exported.txt'));`? I mean, its just a 1 time thing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mysqli, you can use mysqli_multi_query.

so, make a variable with all the sql queries followed by ; and use multi_query

```
$sql = "CREATE ... ; CREATE .....; CREATE ..... ; ";
$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

That should do it.